# How to prevent a flex item height to overflow due to it's content

Tags: css, flexbox

I just started learning flex and so far i'm impressed. However, i'm having an issue with a full page app containing header/footer and three columns.
The first column contain a list of items and since i can't put a fixed height to it's parent, every time the list grow, it push the footer down.

Here's a codepen with the layout : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNVQNj
Html :

```
<html>
<head>
  <body>
    <div class="app-wraper">
      <div class="Navbar"></div>
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="Bidlist">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="tabcontainer">
            </div>
          <div class="content-container">
          <ul class="list-group instruments">
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            <li class="intrument"></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
html,
body {
  background-color: #212121;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* layout */

.app-wraper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.Navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.Bidlist {
  min-width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0px!important;
  padding-right: 1px!important;
  background-color: grey;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px solid #3D3C3D;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.tabcontainer {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.ContentContainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.instruments {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.instrument {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: If you don't add a height, how will the browser know when to wrap or overflow? It's not clear what the problem is,

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add `min-height: 0` to your `.main-content` CSS rule. That prevents that element from stretching to contain its children and pushing the footer offscreen (which is the bad behavior that you're trying to avoid).

This happens because flex items (children of a flex container) establish a [default minimum main-size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto), based on their contents, and will refuse to be smaller than that minimum.  In your case (with the outer flex container being vertically-oriented), "main-size" is `height`, and the flex item in question (`.main-content`) is establishing a content-based `min-height`.

(If you want the list items to be scrollable, then you may want to also add `overflow-y:auto` to `.main-content`)

Comment: I had a similar problem to OP - we had a flex container with a table inside where rows could be added. The height of the container would increase to fit all the rows even if a `max-height` and `overflow-y:auto` was set on the container, but adding `min-height: 0px;` to the container fixed the problem.

Comment: I can't believe how unintuitive this is... but it worked, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank! this solution is so elegant!

Comment: This is absolutely insane. I'm glad I found this answer, it worked like a charm, but why in the world would setting a *minimum* height prevent the *maximum* height from overflowing...

Comment: Great! Worked fine!

Answer (score -3):

Consider specifying your content `height` in order to have a "fix" dimension and use `overflow` to set how you want the overflow for element's box.

For more advance scenario you can consider also using:

- CSS min-height Property
- CSS max-height Property

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/enz7ae5d/

```
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px solid #3D3C3D;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```