# How to create a 100% width and height Flex container with scrolling content

Tags: css, layout, scroll, flexbox, overflow

The layout I'm trying to achieve is a classic header + sidebar + content + footer with flex filling the whole screen.

The thing I can't understand how to do is make the sidebar content fill the screen space (not the html page but the screen) and if its content is taller than the container make it scroll.

[image: Desidered behaviour]

Here the sample code

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lime;
}

.row-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.col-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="side"> side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Look how the content in sidebar is pushing its height making the whole page scroll instead of the sidebar only. The same happen with the content.

[image]

Comment: Can you use `GRID`. It is much easier to do with grid layout.

Comment: Yes I could but I prefer not to. Anyway thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Just added 3 lines to get this working:

1. `max-height: 100vh;` to `.wrapper` to be sure it won't overflow viewport
2. `overflow: auto;` to `.side` to make it scrollable
3. `min-height: 0;` to `.row-wrapper` to prevent it from stretching ([read more in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612613/5597017))

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* added */
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lime;
  /* added */
  overflow: auto;
}

.row-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* added */
  min-height: 0;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.col-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="side"> side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        header
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```